# Book for linux newbies

Tags: linux

Got a friend / next door neighbour who just bought a new computer that came with a linux distro on it (Fedora!). She's been using Windows all the time till now, but now didn't want to pay for new Windows licence, got this for no charge, and she wants to start learning and using it. A bright gal, no doubt about that, but every learning process includes either reading a good book, or asking  a lot of questions, or bugging your neighbour.

So, to save her from the process of learning it the hard way, and in hope that the last two can be avoided, can someone reccomend some book that covers in general "linux way of work and thinking" (I swear, I've no idea  how to put it better than this) ?

And yes, I also was suprised to see Fedora as an preinstalled OS, but for now I don't want to change that since I'm sure drivers hell will occur.

Comment: http://www.linuxnewbieguide.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fedora Linux: A Complete Guide to Red Hat's Community Distribution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596526822).

[Ubuntu for Non-Geeks, 2nd Edition: A Pain-Free, Project-Based, Get-Things-Done Guidebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271522) also seems to have a good buzz and positive reviews though it is Ubuntu based.

Answer (score 7):

O'Reilly offers a [Linux Pocket Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006280/) that is tailored to Fedora:

> *Linux Pocket Guide* gets you up to
>   speed quickly on day-to-day Linux use.
>   The book begins with general concepts
>   like files and directories, the shell,
>   and X windows, and then presents
>   detailed overviews of the most
>   essential commands. You'll learn each
>   command's purpose, usage, options,
>   location on disk, and even the RPM
>   package that installed it. Throw in a
>   host of valuable power user tips and a
>   friendly, accessible style, and you'll
>   find this practical, to-the-point book
>   a small but mighty resource for Linux
>   users.
>
> The *Linux Pocket Guide* is tailored to Fedora Linux--the latest spin-off of Red Hat Linux--but most of the information applies to any Linux system.

For Ubuntu, I would recommend the [Ubuntu Pocket Guide](http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/index_main.html). It helped me start to wade into the world that is Linux-based. They offer [the PDF version of the book](http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/download_main.html) for free, and the same book for sale (in print) on [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1440478295).

Comment: And if she was using Windows, you could recommend her **this** Windows book ;) But the question says Fedora.

Comment: @ linux_is_for_desktop - the link for that would be cool.

Comment: It was rhetorical, just "this Windows book". And the reader imagines that there's really a link to a Windows book ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but you should know one thing about "Linux books for beginners":

Unlike other beginner books about operating systems, a usual Linux beginners book
will in most cases teach you:

- how to use the command line,
- how to compile C/C++ programs,
- how to edit system configuration files,
- how to start/stop services,
- how to write scripts in Perl, Bash, ...

so **nothing** what a usual beginner really **wants** or **needs** to know, to be able to **USE** the operating system.

You have been warned ;)

Comment: No, no. What you say is completely true. I noticed that in books on several computer related subjects.

Answer (score 1):

This is nice web site , which good for beginners to learn to linux  http://www.linuxnewbieguide.org/

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSUSE guides in PDF and HTML format](http://en.opensuse.org/Documentation#Official_Novell_Documentation). These are backed by Novell, and I've found them to be of good quality.

Answer (score 1):

*The Linux Phrasebook* by Scott Granneman is a good starter book. Here's the table of contents:

1. Things to know about your command
   line
2. The basics
3. Learning about commands
4. Building blocks
5. Viewing files
6. Printing and managing print jobs
7. Ownerships and permissions
8. Archiving and compression
9. Finding stuff : easy
10. The find command
11. Your shell
12. Monitoring system resources
13. Installing software
14. Connectivity
15. Working on the network
16. Windows networking

The chapter on installing software is split between deb based (Debian based) systems and rpm based (Red Hat based) systems, so that should work for Fedora.

Comment: Yep, that sounds okey. I found another book on Fedora mentioned da little lower here, so with those two I should be out in the clear!

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the title, the first thing that came to my mind was [rute](http://rute.2038bug.com/index.html.gz).

However, as fellow superuser "linux_is_for_desktop" noted in his [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/21416/book-for-linux-newbies/21423#21423), these books are usually about the command line and the such.

So, to answer your question:

Your best bet is to just explore the system through its menus and various other gui elements. If anything is unclear, you can google or ask on superuser.com.

Comment: Rute is great, but it's not really for someone new to *nix, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Books about **migration** from Windows to Linux would be, from my point of view, most appropriate for a beginner.

Unfortunately, I don't know specific books, but I could find some interesting books searching Amazon and other book stores for

```
windows linux
```

or

```
windows for linux users
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tille's guide](http://tille.garrels.be/training/tldp/), Also in [Hindi](http://geocities.com/linuxparichay)